# Is there any way to know from which Composite Index the data is fetched from?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I would like to know if there is any way to find from which Composite Index the data is fetched from ? The reason is because I have a lot of indexes that are up and running and I am not sure which indexes are required. If I could log the indexes, after a month of tracking the logs, I could clean up the indexes.

I know we could clean up the indexes that are not listed in the local index files, but some indexes where not recorded in the index file and randomly introduced and those which where randomly introduced are needed.

Comment: As it's specified in the documentation, all the necessary indexes are in index.yaml file. Could you explain why do you want to delete only some indexes that are not listed in the local index file? Because all the indexes which are not in the index file are generated randomly and are not needed.

Comment: The issue is am running out of indexes , i am close to the limit provided, so in the future if i would want more indexes to be introduced, i want to delete those which are not being used. The index.yaml file has not been updated properly, that's the reason

Comment: Check this [link about datastore remove index](https://www.mchampaneri.in/2017/12/datastore-remove-index.html)

Comment: the link provided was not helpful, thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

You can only delete or remove the unnecessary indexes with the [Cleanup indexes command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/datastore/cleanup-indexes) which assures that will only remove the unused data. So the indexes which were not updated correctly will remain and other randomly generated or unused indexes will be removed.

Also you can't increase Datastore quota, because per project you can only have 200 composite indexes.

As you mentioned that the cleanup indexes command didn't help with your issue, I created a feature request on [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/148850576) where you can track all the updates related to your issue.